# Datatable Missing operand after 'TruckGrossWeight' operator

Tags: c#, datatable, datatable.select

I have a datatable where I want to assign select query. But following error pops up:**"Syntax error: Missing operand after 'TruckGrossWeight' operator."**

```
DataRow[] drs = dataTableForDropDowns
 .Select("LNGFuelAvailability=" + drpdwnlst_LNGFuelAvailability.SelectedValue + " " +
         "TruckGrossWeight=" + drpdwnlst_TruckGrossCombinedWeight.SelectedValue + "");
```

Value of Selected Values (**int**) are:

```
drpdwnlst_LNGFuelAvailability.SelectedValue= 5
drpdwnlst_TruckGrossCombinedWeight.SelectedValue = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
DataRow[] drs = dataTableForDropDowns.Select("LNGFuelAvailability = "+drpdwnlst_LNGFuelAvailability.SelectedValue+ " AND TruckGrossWeight = "+drpdwnlst_TruckGrossCombinedWeight.SelectedValue);
```

syntax should be like below

```
DataRow[] results = table.Select("A = foo AND B = bar");
```

or

```
DataRow[] results = table.Select("A = foo OR B = bar");
```